# set a background image to a video with transparent background iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have an application where i have a video with a transparent background, i need to set a background image to that video and save it in my gallery or whatever, i have tried playing the video over my view and record the whole screen with something like this:

```
- (void)startScreenRecording {
    self.screenRecorder = [RPScreenRecorder sharedRecorder];
    if (self.screenRecorder.isRecording) {
        return;
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *pathDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *outputURL = pathDocuments[0];

    NSString *videoOutPath = [[outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", arc4random() % 1000]] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mp4"];
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        NSDictionary *videoSettings = @{AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : compressionProperties,
                                        AVVideoCodecKey                 : AVVideoCodecTypeH264,
                                        AVVideoWidthKey                 : width,
                                        AVVideoHeightKey                : height};

        self.assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    [self.assetWriter addInput:self.assetWriterInput];
    [self.assetWriterInput setMediaTimeScale:60];
    [self.assetWriter setMovieTimeScale:60];
    [self.assetWriterInput setExpectsMediaDataInRealTime:YES];

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (granted)
                {
                    [self.screenRecorder setMicrophoneEnabled:YES];

                    [self.screenRecorder startCaptureWithHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef  _Nonnull sampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType bufferType, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if (CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer)) {
                            if (self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown && bufferType == RPSampleBufferTypeVideo) {
                                [self.assetWriter startWriting];
                                [self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)];
                                [videoView play];
                            }

                            if (self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed) {
                                NSLog(@"An error occured.");
                                //show alert
                                [[RPScreenRecorder sharedRecorder] stopCaptureWithHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {}];
                                return;
                            }
                            if (bufferType == RPSampleBufferTypeVideo) {
                                if (self.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                                    [self.assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                                }else{
                                    NSLog(@"Not ready for video");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
                            [session setActive:YES error:nil];
                            // Start recording
                            NSLog(@"Recording started successfully.");
                        }else{
                            //show alert
                        }
                    }];
                }
            });
        }];


    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

but it seems to be low quality and slow, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: It's not easy to explain everything in short comment. But I recommend you read this article using AVVideoComposition to manipulate video, which is much more efficient than using that screen capturing technique.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: thank you for the above, since you have an idea about this, here is my whole problem i have an image view over which i need to show some animations like an airplane flying by or something like that, can you point me in the right direction?